# Is there a way to put the date I entered as a parameter of a query in an msgbox in a text box in an access report?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with many values, what I do in the query is to filter the data between two dates and then graph the top, what I need is that the report shows the dates I enter to know what days it contemplates when I print it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Adding a screenshot/Diagram of what you want to achieve goes a long way in understanding the problem for others and then giving quick solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dynamic parameterized query with a popup input prompt, this would be a calculated field.

`SELECT *, [StartDate] AS Start, [EndDate] AS End FROM tablename WHERE [fieldname] BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate];`

I do not use popup input prompts because they cannot be validated. Advise to use controls on form for user input. Query or report textbox can reference form controls. Like:

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE [fieldname] BETWEEN Forms!formName.tbxStart AND Forms!formName.tbxEnd;`

Comment: According to your comment, my query is like this:

SELECT TOP 3 ASSEMBLY.OPERACION, ASSEMBLY.LLAMADO, Count(ASSEMBLY.OPERACION) AS CONTEO
FROM ASSEMBLY
WHERE (((ASSEMBLY.Area)=True) AND ((ASSEMBLY.FECHA) Between [Start date :] And [End Date:])
GROUP BY ASSEMBLY.OPERACION, ASSEMBLY.LLAMADO
ORDER BY Count(ASSEMBLY.OPERACION) DESC;

What I need is that when I graph the data, somewhere in the graph or in the report, it shows me the dates I entered, this so that when I print the report on paper I know what period of time I am seeing .

Comment: Suggest you have textboxes above graph to show the date range. As I said, use a form for input of criteria.